# Trying to alter 'createdTime' in google docs with Google Apps Script. Getting Error 403 ..."field not writable". Any workaround?

Tags: google-drive-api

**Full error message**:

> Request failed for https://www.googleapis.com returned code 403. Truncated server response: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "fieldNotWritable", "message": "The resource body includes fields which ... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response). (line 13, file "Code")

The code below worked with 'viewedByMeTime' & 'modifiedTime'

```
function myFunction() {
  var newModifiedTime = "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"; 
  var fileId = "1LaKH-wsjgGrCyG6zpbyzsBgsgTah2jQRIIDvDKaaRio";  
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId;

var params = {
    method: "patch",
    headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},//Last time opend by you
    payload: JSON.stringify({createdTime: newModifiedTime}),
    contentType: "application/json",
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
```

Comment: I'm not a real programmer, I just looked at references and guides and imitated the stuff. I got the 'modifiedTime' and 'viewedByMeTime' to change by using the logic above but created time doesn't seem to work the same way despite listed among the other variables. It would be great if someone could type out an answer for me if possible.

Comment: "I'm not a real programmer, I just looked at references and guides and imitated the stuff. "  <-- if you wrote this code then you are a real programmer thats basically the definition of a programmer welcome to the club.

Comment: The `createdTime` parameter is writable only on file creation as it is literally the date and time at which the file was created. What are you trying to do here exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be trying to do a [file.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)

> "fieldNotWritable"

means exactly that not all of the fields can be writen to.  which means you cant update every fields. and create time is one of the fields that you cant update.  if you check the documentation under [request body](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update#request-body) you will see the fields you are allowed to update.